# VBS error message

Tags: vbscript

Why will this Script not work?:

```
pass=inputbox("What Is The Password?") if pass="Taylor" then msgbox("Correct Password!") else strShutdown = "shutdown -s -t 0 -f -m \\" & strComputer      set objShell =    CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   MsgBox "PWNED BY ADMIN"      objShell.Run strShutdown  Wscript.Quit
```

I am trying to make a password so that if someone gets it wrong the cpu shutsdown.

Comment: VBScript requires newlines.

Comment: Yes i used new lines in Vbscript but i could not get the formatting right when i posted it, it was my bad, i was tired. And i am a noob to VBS and programming so i am trying out some basic stuff, that is the point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   
pass=inputbox("What Is The Password?")
if pass="Taylor" then 
    msgbox "Correct Password!" 
else 
    MsgBox "OWNED BY ADMIN"      
    objShell.Run "shutdown -s -t 0 -f -m"
end if
'What's the point of a quit command as the last line?
'Wscript.Quit
```

I fixed even more errors. There is no real point to this script.

Comment: Your script wors except you need a "\\" after the "objShell.Run "shutdown -s -t 0 -f -m"" so it looks like "objectShell.run "shutdown -s -t 0 -f -m \\"

Comment: Why? is it unnecessary?